# SFML C++ Cчетчик нажатий клавиши

Tags: c++, клавиатура, sfml, счетчики

При нажатии enter счетчик int am увеличивается на 1 ;

Должно быть 1 нажатие = один раз +1 но получается +x

почему?

Может быть, проблема со временем? Как исправить?

вот основной цикл

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if(event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        else
        if(event.type == Event::TextEntered){
            if(event.text.unicode>=48 && event.text.unicode<=57){
                temps+=static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
                text2.setString(temps);
            }
        }

    }

    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Return)){/// счетчик нажатий 
        //mas[am]=stoi(temps);
        am++;
        cout<<am;
        temps="";
        text2.setString(temps);
    }
    /*if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::BackSpace)){
        int amount=temps.size();
        if(amount)temps[amount-1]=NULL;
        text2.setString(temps);
        continue;
    }*/

    window.clear();
    //window.draw(shape);

    window.draw(text1);
    window.draw(text2);
    window.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

так попробуйте:

```
bool flag = true;

if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Return)) {
    if (flag) {
        mas[am]=stoi(temps);
        am++;
        cout<<am;
        temps="";
        text2.setString(temps);
        flag = false;
   }
} else {
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: @Skur Понял, спасибо большое))

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще...
можно использовать KeyReleased в лупе событий те будет считать не когда клавиша зажата а когда отпущена

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased){
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return){
                am++;
                cout<<am;
                temps="";
                text2.setString(temps);
            }
        }
```

Comment: будет лучше объединить `(event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased)` и `(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return)`, тогда получиться `((event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return))`. + в том что не нужен лишный `if` блок.